# Does Microsoft publish a list of localized month/ day names

Tags: locale

I would like to have a table / database of localized month/ day names (I am using Windows). I can create this list using a software and the Windows API, but before I venture there, I wonder if there is a public list from Microsoft of

- Month Long Name
- Month Short Name
- Day Long Name
- Day Short Name

.. based on locale.

Or, does microsoft simply implement the [Unicode CLDR](https://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads) definitions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Powershell to get the long and short month and day' names all locales. Open Powershell and enter the following:

```ps
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures([System.Globalization.CultureTypes]::AllCultures) | 
    foreach { $a = $_.DisplayName; 
        $b = $_.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames; 
        $c = $_.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames; 
        $d = $_.DateTimeFormat.DayNames; 
        $e = $_.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames;  
        write "Name: $a `n`tMonths Long Name: $b `n`tMonths Short Name: $c`n`tDays Long Name: $d`n`tDays Short Name: $e`n"
        } | Out-File locales.txt
```

The result is exported to a file named `locales.txt`

If, for example, you want to obtain only for `fr-Fr` or `ja-JP`:

```ps
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures([System.Globalization.CultureTypes]::AllCultures) | 
    where{ $_.Name -eq 'fr-FR' -or $_.Name -eq 'ja-JP' } | 
    foreach { $a = $_.DisplayName; 
        $b = $_.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames; 
        $c = $_.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames; 
        $d = $_.DateTimeFormat.DayNames; 
        $e = $_.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames;  
        write "Name: $a `n`tMonths Long Name: $b `n`tMonths Short Name: $c`n`tDays Long Name: $d`n`tDays Short Name: $e`n"
        } | Out-File locales.txt
```

[image: File with locales]

Comment: I didn't expect such informative answer and doing the work for me. Thank you! Still wondering if Microsoft has such list published, or just follows CLDR. It seems like there are differences in some places.

Comment: @MyICQ I am not sure if Microsoft has a published list. The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267234/why-cldr-and-windows-have-different-currency-formatting) and the comment might give you a partial response.